Best Practices for SQL Replication Password rotation
We use MSSQL Server replication and have a dedicated AD account to attach to everything and everywhere.
We need to rotate the password, but we have yet to do one cleanly and with no issues.
e.g., There will be one subscription that didn't get the message somehow and will stop working.
Can we do things before and after the call to sp_changereplicationserverpasswords to ease the pain (or reduce annoyance)?
Do we need to:
change the distributor or reader agents at the same time?
Restart a service or job, etc...
Any advice or would be welcome

Why not use a gMSA where the password gets rotated automatically?

I recommend you follow the patching sequence for replication while changing the password i.e. 1st Distribution Server, 2nd Publisher and 3rd Subscriber.
Yes, after changing the password you need to stop and start each agent job.
HTH
